# How can I add plain text as a response body to a HttpResponse in Python?

Tags: python, httpresponse, slack

I'm trying to develop a Slack App, and I've currently got it working so that a payload is sent to my webserver, some data is processed and I now want to return the HTTP 200 response required but with a response message included. [Here is the example they use.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loBi4.png)

At the moment I just have `return HttpResponse(status=200)`

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: `requests.get(link).status_code` something like this?

Comment: If using flask
return "Sample text response", 200
https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.Response.status_code